# Open source software projects with PL/SQL codebases?

Tags: oracle, plsql

For the completion of my B.Sc, I'm working on a software tool that can analyze PL/SQL with DML containing references to objects in a database schema(columns/tables). My tool should be able to find, for example, all UPDATE statements that alter a certain column.

So, I'm looking for open source software that has an interesting quantity of Stored Procedures and Triggers with all possible CRUD statements (SELECT/UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE), etc. Sadly, code like Alexandria's [PL/SQL Utils](https://code.google.com/p/plsql-utils/) won't be useful to analyze because it doesn't depend on an existing schema.

So far, I've found just this newly born project: https://code.google.com/p/sysdb/ that has some code, but if you know larger/more complex open codebases in PL/SQL, would be great for me.

Thanks!

Comment: oracle has done a lot of work expanding their dependencies tables in the last releases. how are you planning the handle dynamic sql ?

Answer (score 0):

There are not so many open source projects using PL/SQL, but these might be useful:

- [Tyler Muth's PL/SQL Logger](https://github.com/tmuth/Logger)
- [Steven Feuerstein's UT/PLSQL Unit Testing Framework](http://utplsql.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you contact to the Oracle Application Express team and explain what you're doing, and ask permission to use the ApEx code base for this? Bit of a long shot, but that's a big code base and lots of advanced PL/SQL, but your work could be of use to them (and might get you a job).